# HDevelop record videos

Tags: video, video-recording, halcon, hdevelop

I am using USB3 camera with HDevelop,and I will like to record a video with the real time image. I know that it is possible to take pictures, but I can not find the way to record a video. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

HALCON does not provide the functionality to save taken images as video. However you could use HALCON in one of its language interfaces like HALCON/C++ and a tool like ffmpeg to save the images as video stream. In case that you are restricted to HDevelop you can wrap the [ffmpeg functionality](https://www.libav.org/) in a [HALCON extension package](https://www.mvtec.com/fileadmin/Redaktion/mvtec.com/documentation/manuals/extension_package_programmers_manual.pdf).